# Index of row in WP_List_Table

Tags: wp-list-table

In [`WP_List_Table`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table), the method `column_$custom( $item )`, if implemented, is called once for each row of data that is being displayed in the list table. So, if my list table has three rows of data, then the method `column_$custom( $item )` will be called three times, once for each row

In addition to displaying the data, I need to know the "row index" of the data being displayed. In the above example, I like to extract `0` because it is the first row, `1` for the second, and `2` for the third. Is there a way of knowing the row index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be possible, but it looks pretty complicated. As you have undoubtedly seen, the [`display_rows`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/display_rows/) method just passes a single line and there's no counter. This means that the row number must be in the `$item` variable for you to extract it. Since it is not there natively, you must insert it before you start displaying the table.

Luckily, there is a method expressly designed to do this, [`prepare_items`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/prepare_items/). This is an abstract class, meaning it must be filled in by child classes that use this class. Take, for instance, a look at [the way it is implemented](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_posts_list_table/prepare_items/) in `WP_Posts_List_Table`.

So what you'll have to is override the existing `prepare_items` of the child class you are working with, and loop through the rows to add a new property `$row_count` to each one of them. Then, when you implement column_$custom( $item ) you can extract `$row_count`.

Disclaimer: obviously I didn't test this myself, it's just a concept I think should work.

Comment: I will not override the `prepare_items` method as per your suggestion, however your answer gave me a hint on how to do it. I will create a local variable in the implementation class of `WP_List_Table` called `$row`, and I will update it within the call to the column I wish to track.